# Is this topological sorting exercise correct?

Tags: graph-theory, order-theory

I just want to verify that I understood the concept of toposort since the professor didn't give an exhaustive list of correct answers for the exercises. I need to topologically sort this graph.

[image: Graph and the corresponding Hasse diagram]

If I understood correctly, I have to take out the smallest elements, so 9, 1, 4. Then I have to do it again with 2 and 5, and then 3, and then 6 and 8. The final order would be

$$\{1,4,9 \text{ in arbitrary order}\} \leq \{2, 5 \text{ in arbitrary order}\} \leq 3 \leq \{6, 8 \text{ in arbitrary order}\}$$

Then $7$ isn't connected to any other number so I can place it wherever I want.

Answer (score 1):

#### Yes, this is correct.

<sup>I'm posting this CW answer so that users who **confidently** concur have something to vote on, and so this question doesn't stagnate in the [Unanswered Questions Queue](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=unanswered). If however anyone would like to write a more substantial response to the question, please downvote this answer and post your own.</sup>